# Send a link list by using boost in mpi

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mpi

As I know there is some limitation in the type of data which is being sent in MPI. For example, I can not send a linked list in standard MPI, but I found Boost can do it. I really search the Boost page but in fact it was ambiguous for me and I couldn't understand it. So what is the best way for sending a linked list using Boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it important to use Boost to do this? A quick scan of the Boost documentation doesn't show me anything in there that will do magic for you.

You can send a linked list in MPI, you just need to do a bit of work first. You will need to have a way to pack and unpack your data into buffers. It's relatively simple. There's two ways you can do it.

**The right way:**

1. Use the MPI Datatypes code to create a datatype for your linked list item. I can't tell you exactly how to do this since it depends on what your items look like, but there are lots of good tutorials available on the web that will teach you how to use datatypes and then you can figure it out for your code.
2. Use regular `MPI_SEND`/`MPI_RECV` functions to send your data around using your custom datatype instead of one of the built in datatypes (e.g. `MPI_INT`, `MPI_DOUBLE`, etc.).

**The other way:**

1. Write your own function that packs a list item into a buffer.
2. Send that buffer as a byte array using `MPI_SEND`/`MPI_RECV`.
3. Write another function to unpack that buffer on the receiving side.

The second way looks simpler, but it's really just as complex in the end. It's much better to use MPI datatypes both for making your code cleaner, but also for performance reasons since MPI can do fancy things under the hood to make the datatype code faster that your custom packing/unpacking functions.

Comment: The correct "other way" is using `MPI_Pack()`, not a byte array. It's essentially the same thing (i.e. copying your data to a contiguous buffer and sending it as one message), but with type safety. Still, +1 for the "right way".

Comment: True. There's the "right way", the "other right, but not as good way", and the "other, wrong, but easier to understand way".

Comment: Can someone provide a link to these tutorials for creating your own MPI datatypes?